# Eclipse doesn't see classes from target/generated-sources

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a solution with multiple projects(maven parent pom and a couple of child maven projects). Some of the projects are just a maven project that generates classes from wsdl or xsd using xjc-schema maven plugin.
The plugin generates the classes in target/generated-sources folder.
Now the other projects in the solution has to use the generated classes but eclipse doesn't recognize the generated classes.

Intellij Idea has no problem with that, it can recognize the generated classes, but I want to use Eclipse.

I tried that with Eclipse Neon and Spring Tool Suite based on Neon.

I tried to refresh, restart etc. with no success.
Also tried to add the project with the generated classes to Java Build Path -> Projects of the project that has to use those classes.

Comment: Shouldn't the generated classes be housed in a different directory than "target"?

Comment: is the location (folder) of the generated classes a source folder?

Comment: @MatthiasSchmidt thanks, that was it. When I added the folder as a source folder it looks OK. If you make it an answer - I will accept.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you should make the folder of the generated classes to a source folder.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with a JNI project managed by `nar-maven-plugin`, which generates a class on the fly for loading the native libraries. Making this a source folder solves the problem once it's built, but it creates a new problem that Eclipse thinks the folder is missing after `maven clean` or on first download from source control (since everything under target is excluded). Is there a way to suppress the new error created by following this suggestion?

Answer (score 4):

Also make sure the output folder is correctly set on the java build path. If `Contains Test Sources` is set to `Yes`, the generated classes will not be detectable from your main classes.

[image: Expected Build Path Configuration]

Answer (score 1):

In case that you are already seeing target/generated-sources/... as a source folder in Eclipse but the IDE is still unaware of the generated classes, go to Configure Build Path... and check that there is no Exclusion Pattern set. This was causing the problem in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with the setting the `target/generated-sources` as source folder. I had a subfolder with generated classes, and but `target/generated-sources` set as source folder. Eclipse didn't read the subfolder, though. I removed the `target/generated-sources` and added the `target/generated-sources/<subfolder>` and it worked.